# Print directly from itertools function?

Tags: python, optimization, memory-management, permutation, python-itertools

i wanted to print the 1 millionth permutation of list `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`. I managed this with the code below.

```
import itertools
perm=[]

for i in range(10):
    perm.append(i)
arr=[]
arr=list(itertools.permutations(perm))#stores the permutations in a list

print(arr[(10**6)-1])#prints the 1 millionth permutation
```

This worked because the number of permutations were only 10!~3.6*10^6 all the permutations could fit in memory. However I wished to store all the permutations of the alphabet 26!~4.03*10^26, all these permutations cant fit in memory obviously.

```
import itertools
perm=[]

alphabet="qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm"

for i in alphabet:#stores the letters as separate entries in the list
  perm.append(i)

arr=[]
arr=list(itertools.permutations(perm))

print(arr[(10**6)-1])#prints the 1 millionth permutation
```

The program above crashes and I wouldn't advice running it. An obvious solution would be iterating through the permutations without first storing them in memory and only printing the one millionth permutation.

Comment: _An obvious solution iterating through the permutations without first storing them jn memory and only printing the one millionth permutation_ Yes, that should work. What’s the problem, then?

Comment: I didn't know how to do that, but I figured it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `itertools.islice` on the `itertools.permutations(perm)` generator instead of storing the entire sequence in memory:

```
next(itertools.islice(itertools.permutations(perm), (10**6)-1, None))
```

This returns:

```
('q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'p', 'a', 's', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'l', 'b', 'n', 'z', 'm', 'k', 'c', 'x', 'v', 'j')
```

Comment: I'll try it and get back to you